# Is there a way to override the colors in Ant design Switch Component

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

i need to override the default blue (primary color) on Antd Switch Component when checked and change it to red color. is there a way i can do this?

i have tried using style attribute but it didnt work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the backgroundColor using inline styles like this.

```
<Switch style={{backgroundColor: permission.enabled ? 'green' : 'orange'}}
        checked={permission.enabled}
        checkedChildren={'ENABLED'}
        unCheckedChildren={'DISABLED'}
        onChange={(e) => onPermissionChanged(e, permission)} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `.ant-switch-checked` class like so

```
.ant-switch-checked {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change switch styling by overriding default class (you will get all the element classes from developer tool) for switch class

```
.ant-switch-checked{
   background:#fdfdfd !important;
}
```

as a result it will override the color globally, to override the color for specific element only just wrap the element in some div by giving class "test" and override the css like

```
.test .ant-switch-checked{
   background:#fdfdfd !important;
}
```

and it will update the color for specific elemet only.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main`/`theme`file, you can just override the variable like so:

```
@switch-color: red; // @primary-color
```

or

```
@switch-bg: red; // @component-background;
```

You can actually override any variables to your use: [reference](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less#L826)

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way is utilizing the Ant Design (antd) official theme available after version 5. Here's an example:

```js
<ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        components: { 
          Switch: {
            colorPrimary: "red",
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item label="" name="remember" style={{ color: "white" }}>
         <Switch className="mb-2" />
      </Form.Item>
    </ConfigProvider>
```